# useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions in iOS7 crash

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uicollectionviewlayout

I am building an iOS7 app and I am trying to make use of the new `useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions` effect. I have 2 `UICollectionViewControllers` and when I do the following I get the transition effect

```
SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
secondVC.useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
```

this works fine but what I want to do is make an api call and then in the completion block I want to push onto the nav stack like so

```
[webAPI getDetailsWithParams:params andCompletionBlock:^(id dict) {

    //some work on the result

    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    secondVC.useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];  


} andErrorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

}];
```

but this crashes every time with the following msg

```
 -[UICollectionView _invalidateLayoutWithContext:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17a26400
```

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in this case? How can I get the transition effect when pushing from completion block?

EDIT: by changing it to the following I was able to transition to the second viewcontroller.

```
MyLayout *layout = [[MyLayout alloc] init];
SecondViewController *expandedVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
```

and I also deleted the nib file that went with the file. nib file just consisted of a collection view and it was the file owners view.
While I can now transition I still do not understand why I could not do the previous nib method with in a block. So I would be grateful if someone could shed some light on it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use UICollectionViewController's useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions to make transitions, the layout of the SecondViewController must be known. However, if you use initWithNibName:bundle: initializer, layout is not internally prepared yet, making your desired transitions impossible. As you mentioned in your edited question, you have to use [UICollectionViewController initWithCollectionViewLayout:] to initialize your second UICollectionViewController. Since your xib file has the same name as your class name, SecondViewController.xib is going to be loaded automatically by UIViewController, superclass of UICollectionViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were making UIKit calls from a thread that wasn't the main thread

Comment: no even when I tried making the above forcing block on to main thread it would only work when using initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout and not initWithNibName

Comment: I think its because the integration of collection view into the navigation controller animation only works if you use that initialiser; it just wires up all pushed nav controllers' collections views to the base view controller (collection view controller) and doesn't use the nib